# Proof using induction n!

Tags: discrete-mathematics, induction, proof-explanation

I wanna know how to proof using induction; I saw this example in a discrete book; however, i could not solve it; the question is below:

Prove, using induction, that $3^{n} < n!$ for all $n ≥ 7$

Comment: hint: $3<k+1$ for all integer $k \ge 7$

Comment: we could actually say for all integer $k \ge 3$ but we don't need to know that for this problem... we just need to know that $3<k+1$ does hold for integers $k \ge 7$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initial case: The case clearly holds for $n = 7$. (Easily checked with a calculator)

Inductive hypothesis: $3^{n-1} < (n-1)!$

Inductive step:
$$ 3^n = 3 \cdot 3^{n-1} < 3 (n-1)! < n (n-1)! = n!
$$

I think the purpose of this problem is to demonstrate how to use induction, instead of the importance of the fact $3^n < n!$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what "induction" is ( i'm not an English native speaker ) but that's how I would do it :

First take the case of $n = 7$

$3^7= 2187$ and $7! = 5040 $

so it's true for $n=7$

Then suppose for some $n \geq 7$ that we have $3^n < n! $

now we multiply both sides of by 3 and get

$3^{n+1} < 3(n!)$

and we know $n \leq 7$ so

$3(n!) < (n+1)! $

So if we combine our two above steps we get:

$3^{n+1}< (n+1)!$

There you go! It's true for $n=7$ and  if true for any $n \geq 7$ then it's true for $n+1$ so you can deduce it's true for any $n \geq 7$.

Comment: Is it better now ? I'm sorry if there had been any confusion. It's hard to judge what is obvious to the reader and what is not. I hope the "i" set things clear.

Comment: I think it is a formatting thing. Do you know how to use mathjax?

Comment: The "if it's true fo n = *base case* and if it's true for n $\ge $ *base case* it is true for n+1 so you can deduce it is true for all n $\ge $ *base case" is what "induction" means.

Comment: Yeah I figured given the other answers but I wasn't really sure it was the demonstration the author wanted. Fun fact : here in France it's called " récurrence " =)

Comment: Thanks a lot Christopher for the edit. I will certainly look into mathjax for future contributions, I just found this board and I'm ashamed to say I couldn't resist the urge to try and contribute and skipped the very basics ^^

Answer (score 1):

**First, show that this is true for $n=7$:**

$3^7<7!$

**Second, assume that this is true for $n$:**

$3^n<n!$

**Third, prove that this is true for $n+1$:**

$3^{n+1}=$

$3\cdot\color\red{3^n}<$

$3\cdot\color\red{n!}<$

$7\cdot{n!}<$

$(n+1)\cdot{n!}=$

$(n+1)!$

---

Please note that the assumption is used only in the part marked red.

Comment: What does this " ! "  mean ?

Comment: @ForlanAnWest: Oh, wow... You're asking how to prove by induction an expression which you don't even know how to read? I think you should start off with something a little more basic before jumping to induction. In any case, $n!=1\times2\times3\times\dots\times n$.